# Listener method to fetch image from Firebase Storage iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, image, firebase, storage

I am implementing chat using Firebase ,do anyone know what is listener method for FIRStorage. i have succeeded in fetching new messages from FIRDatabase using its listener

`_refHandle = [[_ref child:@"messages"] observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeChildAdded withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot *snapshot)`

i need similar listener method for FIRStorage

Comment: What do you want to achieve??

Comment: just need to get images from the firebase storage, whenever new images arrives some method need to get invoked is what i want..

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is save the picture url in your database when someone upload it, and then use this code you provided.

I don't think it's possible to do it just using Firebase Storage

Comment: thanks for your reply mate..but i found the solution..!!

Comment: @Zღk Can you share the solution please. I'm looking for it.